# How to show that $ Ax \le b$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

For

$$ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^m, c \in \mathbb{R}  $$

one has to show that

$$ K:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: Ax \le b \}$$

is convex.

Now I'm aware that by definition, a set is convex $ \iff $ for all $x,y \in K, \lambda \in [0,1]$ any point $ \lambda x + (1- \lambda) y$ is again $ \in K$.

However, I do not see how to apply that here. Can you give me any directions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell if the hints have been useful?

Comment: Yep, indeed they were ... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try first the case where $m=n=1$.

The general case is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

$Ax\le b$ implies $\lambda Ax\le \lambda b$, if $\lambda\ge0$.

Thus if $x,y\in K$ and $0\le\lambda\le1$, you have

$$
A(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)
=\lambda Ax + (1-\lambda)Ay\le \lambda b+(1-\lambda)b=b
$$

We use also that $x\le x'$ and $y\le y'$ implies $x+y\le x'+y'$.